# Is there any boolean algebra expression that can not be put into 3SAT?

Tags: boolean-logic, algebra, boolean-operations

This seems to me pretty obvious, There is not but I might be leaving a special case.
As I see it 1SAT (only one literal per clause) and 2SAT can be easily transformed into 3SAT.
An any clause with more than 3 literas has been proven it can be transformed into 3SAT.
So maybe the question should be asked as:
Do all boolean algebra can be put into SAT? or
can we define boolean algebra with ony these operators? AND OR and NOT

Comment: is this a homework? Why do you need the proof?

Comment: I am studying the pnp question for fun.

Comment: 3sat is Complete theory. you can describe NAND by 4 3sat expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

I will not give the full proof but here is the main idea: Write the given formula in a normal form i.e. conjunction of disjunctions. Use induction on the number of variables on an expression. Pick the longest subexpression with n+1 variables, introduce a new variable for some part of subexpression to leave an expression of n variables, add the constraints for the new variable to the formula, repeat the procedure as many times as needed to have a formula where the longest subexpression has n variables.